# Birt report with hibernate

Tags: java, report, jboss7.x, birt

Hi I'm trying to find a way to create birt reports with datasets based on a hibernate data source. However, I downloaded eclipse report designer and related plugins, but can't seem to find an option for hibernate data source. Was this functionality taken out?

I have gone through a couple of links and either they are old libraries or the integration is done via seam. The only reasonable examples i found are using Scripted data source to access hibernate POJOs. But nothing on how to access hibernate entities directly from the report at least in the latest versions of birt.

Or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=reporting+hibernate+data+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=rSxrVNCrOaWo8wfkwYDoAQ#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=birt+reporting+hibernate+data+source

Comment: I have gone through a couple of links and either they are old libraries or the integration is done via seam. The only reasonable examples i found are using Scripted data source to access hibernate POJOs. But nothing on how to access hibernate entities directly from the report at least in the latest versions of birt.

Comment: If I where you I would update the question with these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my approach based on POJO data source (without using scripting data source). I finally found some time today to describe it [here](http://lifeinide.com/post/2014-12-25-birt-with-hibernate-using-pojos/).